# How can I remove the transient during construction?

Tags: python

I have a program that builds a picture. But I need to remove the moment of promotion. I tried to do it with t.trans and numpy, but an error occurs.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


с0 = 0.08
c1 = 10
c11=7
c3 = 3
m0=1
m1=2
m=m0/m1
t_trans=np.array((59, 100,5000))
def f(x):
    f = ((-m)*x)+(1/2)*((m0+m1)/m1)*(abs(x+1.0)-abs(x-1.0))
    return f
def dH_dt(H, t=0):
        return np.array([(-c1/c3)*f(H[1]-H[0]),
                     (-1/c3)*(f(H[1]-H[0])+H[2]),
                     c3*H[1],
                     (-c11/c3)*f(H[4]-H[3]),
                     (-1/c3)*(f(H[4]-H[3])+H[5])+(с0/c3)*(H[1]-H[4]),
                     c3*H[4]])

t = np.linspace(1000, 1800, 5000)
H0 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
H, infodict = integrate.odeint(dH_dt, H0, t, full_output=True)
fig = plt.figure()
if t>t_trans:
    plt.plot(H[:,0], H[:,2])
    plt.show()
```

The resulting curve:
[image]

The part of the curve I want to remove:
[image]

Comment: What specifically do you mean with moment of promotion?

Comment: Do you  want to plot certain elements of H depending on a comparison between t and t_trans? Which time steps do you want to exclude?

Comment: Yes,i want remove first 600 time steps

Comment: I add two picture, in first what I have and on second, what need remove.I think its on first 600 steps.The main thing is to understand how to write it down, but you can pick it up later

Comment: Can you explain what `t_trans` is used for? I think you can do that with slicing: `plt.plot(H[600:,0], H[600:,2])`.

Comment: "an error occurs" is not very specific

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude the first 600 entries of `H` from the plot with slicing. I also cleaned up your code a little bit, here is the result:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x, m0=1, m1=2):
    m=m0/m1
    f = ((-m)*x) + (1/2) * ((m0+m1)/m1) * (abs(x+1.0) - abs(x-1.0))
    return f

def dH_dt(H, t=0, c0=0.08, c1=10, c11=7, c3=3):
    return np.array([(-c1/c3) * f(H[1]-H[0]),
                 (-1/c3) *( f(H[1]-H[0]) + H[2]),
                 c3 * H[1],
                 (-c11/c3) * f(H[4]-H[3]),
                 (-1/c3) * (f(H[4]-H[3]) + H[5]) + (c0/c3) * (H[1]-H[4]),
                 c3 * H[4]])

t = np.linspace(1000, 1800, 5000)
H0 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
H, _ = integrate.odeint(dH_dt, H0, t, full_output=True)

fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(H[600:,0], H[600:,2])
plt.show()
```

This is the resulting image:
[image]